# svn: XML data was not well-formed

Tags: macos, svn

I've been having a bit of a problem with Subversion on my Mac running Lion. Anytime I try to checkout any repository I always get this error:

```
svn: XML data was not well-formed
```

Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have close to none experience with subversion.

Comment: What Subversion version do you use?

Comment: And one more question: does this happen with every SVN repository or only with one certain?

Comment: This happens with every svn repo I try. For the version that I'm using, it's the default one shipped with Lion, so (I think) its 1.6.16.

Comment: (I'm not at my computer right now.)

Comment: Looks like a bug. When SVN checks out a repository it creates a some kind of operations journal (it is called "log") in XML format to make operations transactional. SVN creates these XML logs first, and then runs the operations they describe. I suspect that SVN forms incorrect log files that cannot parse later (for instance, if there's a commit with an author with an ACSII character < 0x20 in it).

Comment: What you may do in this case: or use SVN >= 1.7 that creates logs not in XML format but in SQLite database, hence has no such problem; or you may try SVNKit-based clients (SVNKit has another XML parser): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVNKit#Adoption

Comment: You may analyze .svn/log file to realize why XML parser considers it invalid. Please, comment if you find the reason.

Comment: Do you have parental controls enabled on your user account? If so, try disabling them and rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have faced a lot of problem due to this strange error. Seems like when svn has conflicting auth data in existing .ssh folder it gets this error.

Answer (score -1):

Please delete (rename in case you want a backup) ~/.ssh and ~/.subversion directories. Deleting only .ssh should work.

Comment: Could you explain what your user home's `.ssh` folder has to do with it?

Comment: I have faced this problem, and deleting those directories solved it. Moreover i already suggested a to have a backup.